# is it possible to add a value to a global variable from inside of a local switch in C?

Tags: c

I have a program for the use of being able to select college courses then assign a price based off credit hours. Current I have created a function that runs a swtich to differentiate each course from eachother and then prints it. At the beginning of each switch loop it resets the values.

My problem is im trying to figure out how to have the amount of credit hours assigned capped. For instance, if I picked 3 classes, but the credit hour became over 7, It needs to print an error saying "too many credit hours chosen".

I figured I might be able to add another variable inside the switch where the credit hours would add up then I could just make an easy if else or something, but I havent learned about local or global variables yet so im not sure if creating a value in a local variable can be called globally.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>


int studentId, var, i;
float first;
int course, course1, course2;
float second, amount;
float credit2, credit3, credit4, credit5, credit6, credit7, credit8;
float paymentA, paymentB, paymentC, paymentD, total = 0;
float creditA, creditB;
char newInvoice, Y = 1, N = 0;




void courseInfo(int myCourse){
    float credit1 = 0;
    char a[7];
    switch(myCourse)
    {
             case 4587:
                credit1 = 4;
                strcpy(a, "MAT 236");
                break;
            case 4599:
                credit1 = 3;
                strcpy(a,"COP 220");
                break;
            case 8997:
                credit1 = 1;
                strcpy(a, "GOL 124");
                break;
            case 9696:
                credit1 = 5;
                strcpy(a, "COP 100");
                break;
            case 4580:
                credit1 = 3;
                strcpy(a, "MAT 230");
                break;
            case 4581:
                credit1 = 4;
                strcpy(a, "MAT 231");
                break;
            case 4582:
                credit1 = 2;
                strcpy(a, "MAT 232");
                break;
            case 4583:
                credit1 = 2;
                strcpy(a,  "MAT 233");
                break;
            case 3587:
                credit1 = 4;
                strcpy(a, "MAT 256");
                break;
            case 4519:
                credit1 = 3;
                strcpy(a, "COP 420");
                break;
            case 6997:
                credit1 = 1;
                strcpy(a, "GOL 127");
                break;
            case 9494:
                credit1 = 3;
                strcpy(a, "COP 101");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Sorry invalid entry!\n\n");
                }
        total = total + (credit1*120.25);
        printf("%.2d\t%s\t\t%.2f\t\t$ %.2f\n\n", myCourse, a, credit1 , credit1*120.25);

}

return 0;
}
```

Im thinking if I can store something else like 'flag' variable that gets the same credit hours stored and added up, then called into an if function outside the switch, then I could write it an error for choosing too many. Not sure if this is possible. Thank you

Comment: Never use float numbers for money!

Comment: @0andriy noted!

Comment: perhaps <O/T>, but in `courseInfo` you invoke undefined behavior with your `strcpy` calls. `strcpy` appends a `NUL` terminator, which in this case is one past your array. Change that to `char a[8];`

Comment: in terms of the general flow, there's no need for all the globals, they can surely all go in `main`. There is a lot of repeated `printf` code as well. Looks like to me the only thing that changes based on `amount` is the call(s) to `courseInfo`, try whittling down the code to print that info to only one place. Also, you treat `amount` as an `int`, so make it an `int`, it doesn't need to be a `float`

Comment: *"but I havent learned about local or global variables yet..."* -- for not having learned about *global* variables -- you sure are using a lot of them -- which should be avoided. In fact, for an overwhelming majority of the code you write, you should not use gloabals at all. Instead, you should declare the variables within the scope they are needed and pass the values as parameters to any function that needs them. In `void courseInfo(int myCourse)` you could pass the current credit total and return an updated current credit total -- or simply pass a pointer to the total.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &newInvoice);` invokes *Undefined Behavior*. You cannot use `%s` to save into a single `char`. Use `%c` for that purpose -- and **validate every return**. `scanf` is a horrible way to take user input for new C programmers. Instead use `fgets` (and don't skimp on buffer size) so you can ensure you consume an entire line of input at a time. Then call `sscanf` to parse the value you need from the filled buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you already have a valid answer to one of your problems, there are many, many more issues with your code. I commend your effort to learn, and a menuing project is always a good learning experience, you have to handle your input properly to avoid *Undefined Behavior* or invoking infinite loops.

**Why `scanf` Gives New C Programmers Trouble**

`scanf` is notorious for giving new C programmers fits due to subtle (and not so subtle) issues that arise from its misuse. Specifically, `scanf` (and family) does not consume all characters in the line of input entered by the user. Further, if there is a mismatch between what the user enters and the conversion specifier used, a *matching failure* occurs, character extraction ceases, and the character(s) causing the failure are left in the input stream *unread* waiting to bite you again on the next attempted input. Complicating matters, what *is* left in the input stream by `scanf` depends on the *conversion specifier* used. Unless each of these is properly handled by the programmer, bad things will happen in your code.

Contrast the problem using `scanf` for input with the simplicity of using a *line-oriented* input function like `fgets` which when provided with a sufficiently sized buffer, will consume the entire line of input provided by the user. You can't be bitten by something `scanf` left in the input stream. Further, after reading an entire line of input into a properly sized buffer, `sscanf` can be use to parse the needing information from the filled buffer without risk of a *matching failure* affecting the next attempted user input.

In your use of `scanf`, you fail to check the return on every occasion, e.g.

```
    scanf("%f", &amount);
```

You have no way of knowing whether `amount` actually contains a value, or whether the user slipped reaching for the `5` key and tapped `'r'` instead. That is an open invitation to *Undefined Behavior*. Further, as mentioned in my comment, you affirmatively invoke *Undefined Behavior* with:

```
    scanf("%s", &newInvoice);
```

You cannot use `%s` to save into a single char. At minimum a *string* (which is what the `"%s"` specifier denotes, requires 2-characters of storage (one for the character and one for the *nul-terminating* character)

**Use A Line-Oriented Input Function Instead (like `fgets` of POSIX `getline`)**

Instead, let's look at how to use `fgets` and handle any input errors that may result. To begin, if you need a constant to declare a buffer, `#define` the size or use an `enum` to accomplish the same thing. Avoid using *magic-numbers*. E.g.

```
#define NCRS    3   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXA   64   /* (do NOT skimp on buffer sizes) */
#define MAXC 1024
...
int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "";    /* only variable needed outside loop */

    do {    /* loop continually until user chooses No more invoices */
        int sid, ncrs, n = 0, crsno[NCRS] = {0};
        double total = 0.0;

        /* get student ID (sid) */
        printf("\nPlease enter Student ID: ");
        if (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {             /* read entire line */
            if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &sid) != 1) {    /* parse int value */
                fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
                continue;   /* on invalid int - get another */
            }
        }
        else {  /* on manual EOF (ctrl+d on Linux, or ctrl+z on windows) */
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
            return 1;   /* gracefully exit */
        }
        ...
```

Look at what occurs above. First the maximum number of characters for the buffer (`MAXC`) is defined as `1024` which should be more than sufficient to handle the anticipated input (and handle a cat stepping on the keyboard). `buf[MAXC]` is declared as the buffer to hold the user input and the call to `fgets` is made to store the line of input containing the student ID (`sid`), e.g.

```
        printf("\nPlease enter Student ID: ");
        if (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {             /* read entire line */
        ...
        }
        else {  /* on manual EOF (ctrl+d on Linux, or ctrl+z on windows) */
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
            return 1;   /* gracefully exit */
        }
```

`fgets` returns `NULL` on `EOF`, otherwise it returns a pointer to `buf`. You check the return to handle the case where the user generates a manual `EOF` (<kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> on Linux or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windows). If the user cancels input by generating a manual `EOF`, you will generally want to gracefully exit your code (or at least that input block).

After you have the line of input, you can call `sscanf` to parse the value from `buf` (as you were attempting with the call to `scanf` in your code). However, note by using `fgets`, you have already validated that you have a line of input, and now you can separately and independently validate parsing the information from that line into your needed value, e.g.

```
        ...
            if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &sid) != 1) {    /* parse int value */
                fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
                continue;   /* on invalid int - get another */
            }
```

Since this is the first input within the Invoice loop, if an invalid integer is read, you can simply `continue` and prompt for the student ID again. This ensures you will have a valid student ID entered before you proceed further in your program, or else the user has canceled input and you exit.

The same approach would apply to all the remaining inputs in your program.

**Providing A Meaningful Return Type For `courseInfo` Will Solve Your `total` Problem**

The next issue you raise is how to keep a running total from your repeated calls to `courseInfo`. This can be handled easily by changing the **return** type for `courseInfo` so that it (1) can report whether the function succeeded or failed, and (2) return that information in a way it provides needed information (like the cost of the course number used as input to the function (or returns `0` indicating an invalid course number was provided). As noted in the comments, you should not use floating point for currency as rounding errors will occur. (however, for your exercise here, they will be fine, but for real-world currency handling, use an exact type)

So how to handle the total? Since you code asks the user to enter up to a maximum of 3 course numbers, a simple way to handle the input is just to read the course numbers into an array. Then, after confirming they were valid course numbers, all you need to do is loop over your array, adding the returned cost to your running total. For example, notice the course number array (`crsno[NCRS]`) declared at the top of your loop. After the user has entered the number of course, you can simply loop filling the array using the same input technique and validations we introduce above, e.g.

```
        /* loop until array filled with ncrs valid course numbers */
        printf ("Enter the %d course number(s)\n", ncrs);
        do {
            printf ("  enter course[%d]: ", n + 1); /* add 1 for display */
            if (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {         /* read line/validate */
                if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &crsno[n]) == 1 &&
                    lookup (crsno[n])) {    /* lookup valid no. ? */
                    n++;    /* only increment array index if valid course */
                }
                else
                    fputs ("error: invalid course no.\n", stderr);
            }
            else {
                fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
                return 1;
            }
        } while (n < ncrs);
```

The `crsno` array now holds the number of valid course numbers requested by the user. (the `lookup (crsno[n])` function does just that, it consults a lookup table of your course numbers to ensure the number entered by the user was valid -- shown in the example below)

With your array filled, you are now ready to output your invoice. **Note:** you only need a single `printf` call to output a continual block of text (no matter how many lines). So do output the invoice, you simply output the header information for the invoice, then loop over your `crsno` array passing each course number to your `courseInfo` function summing the total and outputting the details from within `courseInfo` and finally outputting the footer information with the total and prompting whether the user wants to print another invoice, e.g.

```
        /* you only need 1 printf to output all continous text */
        printf ("\nVALENCE COMMUNITY COLLEGE\nORLANDO FL 10101\n"
                "---------------------\n\n"
                "Fee Invoice Prepared for Student V%d\n\n"
                "1 Credit Hour = $120.25\n"
                "CRN\tCR_PREFIX\tCR_HOURS\n", sid);

        /* loop over array outputting course specifics, summing total */
        for (int i = 0; i < ncrs; i++)
            total += courseInfo(crsno[i]);

        /* output total and prompt to print another */
        printf ("\tHealth & id fees\t$ 35.00\n\n"
                "--------------------------------------\n"
                "\tTotal Payments\t    $  %.2f\n\n"
                "Would you like to print another invoice (Y/N): "
                , total +35.00);
```

**Putting It Altogether**

Putting it altogether in a short example, you could do something similar to the following. Think through the logical flow of each of the loops. If you are going to ask whether the user wants to print another invoice, then all your code dealing with the invoice must be contained within an outer loop. Also notice what *scope* the variables are declared within. The only variable declared outside the invoice loop is `buf` and that is only because it is reused for all input and then compare in the `while ()` condition of the `do { } while ();` loop requiring it to be visible outside the loop.

The only global variable declared is the lookup table -- and that is generally one of the limited cases where globals need be used. Otherwise, all variables, aside from `buf` are declared within the scope (body) of the invoice loop, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define NCRS    3   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXA   64   /* (do NOT skimp on buffer sizes) */
#define MAXC 1024

int valid[] = { 4587, 4599, 8997, 9696, /* valid course lookup table */
                4580, 4581, 4582, 4583,
                3587, 4519, 6997 };

#define NVALID sizeof valid / sizeof *valid

/* simple lookup function, returns 1 if course valid, 0 otherwise */
int lookup (int course)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NVALID; i++)
        if (course == valid[i])
            return 1;

    return 0;
}

/* function prototype for courseInfo - defintion moved to end */
double courseInfo (int myCourse);

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "";    /* only variable needed outside loop */

    do {    /* loop continually until user chooses No more invoices */
        int sid, ncrs, n = 0, crsno[NCRS] = {0};
        double total = 0.0;

        /* get student ID (sid) */
        printf("\nPlease enter Student ID: ");
        if (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {             /* read entire line */
            if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &sid) != 1) {    /* parse int value */
                fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
                continue;   /* on invalid int - get another */
            }
        }
        else {  /* on manual EOF (ctrl+d on Linux, or ctrl+z on windows) */
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
            return 1;   /* gracefully exit */
        }

        for (;;) {  /* loop until valid number of courses (ncrs) entered */
            printf ("Enter how may courses-up to 3: ");
            if (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {           /* read entire line */
                if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &ncrs) != 1) { /* same validations */
                    fputs ("error: not an integer value\n", stderr);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else {
                fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
                return 1;
            }
            if (0 <= ncrs && ncrs <= 3) /* additional range check */
                break;
            else
                fputs ("error: valid no. of courses is 0-3.\n", stderr);
        }

        /* loop until array filled with ncrs valid course numbers */
        printf ("Enter the %d course number(s)\n", ncrs);
        do {
            printf ("  enter course[%d]: ", n + 1); /* add 1 for display */
            if (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {         /* read line/validate */
                if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &crsno[n]) == 1 &&
                    lookup (crsno[n])) {    /* lookup valid no. ? */
                    n++;    /* only increment array index if valid course */
                }
                else
                    fputs ("error: invalid course no.\n", stderr);
            }
            else {
                fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
                return 1;
            }
        } while (n < ncrs);

        /* you only need 1 printf to output all continous text */
        printf ("\nVALENCE COMMUNITY COLLEGE\nORLANDO FL 10101\n"
                "---------------------\n\n"
                "Fee Invoice Prepared for Student V%d\n\n"
                "1 Credit Hour = $120.25\n"
                "CRN\tCR_PREFIX\tCR_HOURS\n", sid);

        /* loop over array outputting course specifics, summing total */
        for (int i = 0; i < ncrs; i++)
            total += courseInfo(crsno[i]);

        /* output total and prompt to print another */
        printf ("\tHealth & id fees\t$ 35.00\n\n"
                "--------------------------------------\n"
                "\tTotal Payments\t    $  %.2f\n\n"
                "Would you like to print another invoice (Y/N): "
                , total +35.00);

        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin))
            break;
    } while (tolower (*buf) == 'y');

    return 0;
}

/* choose meaningful return type that can indicate success/failure
 * and can also return needed information. returns cost of credits,
 * or zero indicating failure.
 */
double courseInfo (int myCourse)
{
    int credit1 = 0;
    double cost = 0.0;
    char a[MAXA];       /* don't use magic-number, use a constant */

    switch(myCourse)
    {
        case 4587:
            credit1 = 4;
            strcpy(a, "MAT 236");
            break;
        case 4599:
            credit1 = 3;
            strcpy(a,"COP 220");
            break;
        case 8997:
            credit1 = 1;
            strcpy(a, "GOL 124");
            break;
        case 9696:
            credit1 = 5;
            strcpy(a, "COP 100");
            break;
        case 4580:
            credit1 = 3;
            strcpy(a, "MAT 230");
            break;
        case 4581:
            credit1 = 4;
            strcpy(a, "MAT 231");
            break;
        case 4582:
            credit1 = 2;
            strcpy(a, "MAT 232");
            break;
        case 4583:
            credit1 = 2;
            strcpy(a,  "MAT 233");
            break;
        case 3587:
            credit1 = 4;
            strcpy(a, "MAT 256");
            break;
        case 4519:
            credit1 = 3;
            strcpy(a, "COP 420");
            break;
        case 6997:
            credit1 = 1;
            strcpy(a, "GOL 127");
            break;
        case 9494:
            credit1 = 3;
            strcpy(a, "COP 101");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Sorry invalid entry!\n\n");
            return 0;
    }

    cost = credit1 * 120.25;
    printf ("%.2d\t%s\t\t%d\t\t$ %.2f\n\n", 
            myCourse, a, credit1 , credit1 * 120.25);

    return cost;
}
```

(**note:** the inclusion of `ctype.h` to convert the `Y/N` character entered to lowercase so a single comparison can handle `Yy` to determine if the user selected another)

**Example Use/Output**

The invalid numbers were intentionally entered to force the error handling in the code.

```
$ ./bin/courseinv

Please enter Student ID: 1234
Enter how may courses-up to 3: 8997
error: valid no. of courses is 0-3.
Enter how may courses-up to 3: 3
Enter the 3 course number(s)
  enter course[1]: 8997
  enter course[2]: 4583
  enter course[3]: 4519

VALENCE COMMUNITY COLLEGE
ORLANDO FL 10101
---------------------

Fee Invoice Prepared for Student V1234

1 Credit Hour = $120.25
CRN     CR_PREFIX       CR_HOURS
8997    GOL 124         1               $ 120.25

4583    MAT 233         2               $ 240.50

4519    COP 420         3               $ 360.75

        Health & id fees        $ 35.00

--------------------------------------
        Total Payments      $  756.50

Would you like to print another invoice (Y/N): y

Please enter Student ID: 1235
Enter how may courses-up to 3: 2
Enter the 2 course number(s)
  enter course[1]: 10
error: invalid course no.
  enter course[1]: 3587
  enter course[2]: 6997

VALENCE COMMUNITY COLLEGE
ORLANDO FL 10101
---------------------

Fee Invoice Prepared for Student V1235

1 Credit Hour = $120.25
CRN     CR_PREFIX       CR_HOURS
3587    MAT 256         4               $ 481.00

6997    GOL 127         1               $ 120.25

        Health & id fees        $ 35.00

--------------------------------------
        Total Payments      $  636.25

Would you like to print another invoice (Y/N): n
```

Finally, with any input routine you write -- go try and break it. If it breaks, fix it and try again. That is the only way you will discover corner-cases that need additional work (and there may be many above, the code above isn't thoroughly tested, but should handle most foreseeable abuses)

Look things over, the key is *validate, validate, validate*. If a user can do something dumb with your code -- they will. Protect against as many abuses as you can logically see. Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: yes, that is no problem at all. In terms of *what you can do* with a variable (in terms of assignment, addition, etc), C does not care whether the variable you use is local or global. A global variable will keep its value after the function returns. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * last_value = "none";  /* this is global */

void foo(int type)
{
    switch (type) {
        case 1:
            last_value = "one";
            break;
        default:
            last_value = "other";
            break;
    }
}

int main()
{

    printf("last: %s\n", last_value);

    foo(1);
    printf("last: %s\n", last_value);

    foo(39);
    printf("last: %s\n", last_value);

    return 0;
}
```

The output will be:

```
last: none
last: one
last: other
```

Comment: What you are doing is fine, but you should make sure the OP understands the limitations of playing with *string literals*.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your Question if you could create a local variable an assign values to it globally, the answer is no. That's why there is a difference between local an global variables.

To why it is a bad idea to use float values for numbers that have to be precise check out this wiki page: [IEE 754 wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

In general you can go one of two ways. Either assign a global variable and use it to share data between functions, or pass the corresponding variable to every function.

Let's look at your code.
Generally you don't need that many global variables. Most of them can go into the main function.
There are at lot of `printf` in your code. You can outsource those to a function too. (everything that you use more than once goes into a function).

Float is a datatype designed to calculate fractions. If you do not need those, don't use them (e.g. `courseInfo`).

Your switch-case is not easy to read. Have a look at the `enum` data type [Enums](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-enumeration)

That way your code is easier to understand and to maintain.

I hope I could help you.